# How to run gimp like it's a normal python file?

Tags: python, cmd, gimp

So example I have got an effects.py file and to run on the command prompt, I am doing
`gimp-console-2.10.exe -idf --batch-interpreter python-fu-eval -b "import effects; effects.data()"` and this works.

However I don't really want to run it in this way. Is there a way I could run it like `python effects.py` on the command prompt instead?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from gimpfu import *

def data():
    pass
```

Comment: Not as far as I know. OTOH I don't see what gain you would expect, you would still have to start a Gimp process. However, if your `effect.py` is using GEGL functions these can be used in a CLI environment using the `gegl` executable.

Comment: @xenoid I am doing this because of some sort of requirements for my work. It can't have those import stuff. Or if could get some advice to run it something like this?
`gimp-console-2.10.exe -idf --batch-interpreter python-fu-eval -b effects.py` ? Would that be possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid the import, you can install your python code as a regular plugin, and then you should be able to skip the import and call your plugin directly:

```
gimp-console-2.10.exe -idf --batch-interpreter python-fu-eval -b "pdb.python_fu_your_registration_atom(...)"
```

(not tested)